# Parse fetchIfNeeded() not working

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have 2 pointer objects(pointing to ParseUser) in my table "Attack".It seems these pointer objects take a while to get retrieved.Hence my code directly didnt work and gave me the exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for this key.  Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.
```

I then did the needful surrounding the fetchIfNeeded function with a try-catch block:

```
ParseObject battle = null;
try {
   battle = objects.get(0).fetchIfNeeded();
} catch (ParseException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
ParseUser attacker1 = battle.getParseUser("Attacker");
Log.i("dontest",attacker1.getUsername());
```

It is still returning the same.I even checked with `isDataAvailable` function and it returned true.Any way around this?

**P.S.:** My query returns exactly 1 row which I checked with the `size()` function.

Here's the [documentation](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#fetchIfNeeded%28%29) describing fetchIfNeeded() function.

Answer (score 6):

Use Your query like this..

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQueryFromAttack = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Attack");
// use include to fetch details while quering----increase loading speed by doing this.
pQueryFromAttack.include("pointer to _user table");
List<ParseObject> listObj = pQueryFromAttack.find();
```

for eg:

```
 String userName =listObj.get(0).fetchIfNeeded().getString("name");
```

Use it like this...